# How to create an Archive Table with a Mysql Procedure and Date()

Tags: mysql, date, procedure, archive

I try to create a procedure which runs once a day and stores a subset of data from a bigger Table. The Name of this table should be dynamically created with CURDATE().

```
    DROP PROCEDURE daily_backup;
    DELIMITER |
    CREATE PROCEDURE daily_backup()
    BEGIN
      SET @tbl = CONCAT('items_data_', DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y%m%d'));
      SET @s = CONCAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ', @tbl);
      PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
      EXECUTE stmt;

      @s = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE `', @tb1, '` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL,`up` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,`down` mediumint(9) NOT NULL) ENGINE=Archive');

      PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
      EXECUTE stmt;

      SET @s = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ', @tbl, ' SELECT id,up,down FROM items;');
      PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
      EXECUTE stmt;
    END
```

These are the results

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@s = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE `', @tb1, '` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL,`up` mediumint(9) ' at line 8

**EDIT** // Working now

```
    DROP PROCEDURE daily_backup;
    DELIMITER |
    CREATE PROCEDURE daily_backup()
    BEGIN
      SET @tbl = CONCAT('items_data_', DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y%m%d'));
      SET @s = CONCAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ', @tbl);
      PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
      EXECUTE stmt;

      SET @s = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE `', @tbl, '` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL,`up` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,`down` mediumint(9) NOT NULL) ENGINE=Archive');

      PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
      EXECUTE stmt;

      SET @s = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ', @tbl, ' SELECT id,up,down FROM items;');
      PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
      EXECUTE stmt;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable assignments always need a `SET` command:

```
SET @s = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE `', @tbl, '` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL,`up` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,`down` mediumint(9) NOT NULL) ENGINE=Archive');
```

Note that you have `@tb1` in this statement, it should be `@tbl`.

It's also good practice to `DEALLOCATE` a prepared statement after you use it i.e.

```
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

after the `EXECUTE stmt`

Comment: If i try to run the procedure now i get this error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1 after "CALL daily_backup();"

Comment: @kejith you have `@tb1` in this statement, not `@tbl`.